# what is the log format of elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging

Sample Format of elasticsearch log: `[2017-08-30T06:27:19,158][WARN ][o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService] [Glsuj_2] [gc][296816] overhead, spent [1.2s] collecting in the last [1.3s]`

Can you please explain me what does it mean? when we observe the log?
please explain me each and every word in the log?

what is meant by `o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService` ?

what is meant by `Glsuj_2`?

what is meant by `gc`?

what is meant by `296816`?

Answer (score 2):

The log messages are composed within the [JvmGcMonitorService class](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/monitor/jvm/JvmGcMonitorService.java).
I think this is the best place to lookup the logging semantics. A trouble ticket asking for documentation on github [is still open](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17491).

This also applies to the more involved warnings, like the `SLOW_GC_LOG_MESSAGE`.

### Answering (parts of) your question directly

`o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService` - the abbreviated qualified name of the logging class

`Glsuj_2` your node name

`gc` - "Garbage collection" - 'gc' is hardcoded in the log string

`296816` - a sequence number, incremented when the gc is monitored

But the interesting part of the log starts after it: `spent [1.2s] collecting in the last [1.3s]`. Again: the parts inside the brackets are filled in by the JvmGcMonitorService.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Tommy's response, The Log file will contain the following details.

```
[gc][{}][{}][{}] duration [{}], collections [{}]/[{}], total [{}]/[{}], memory [{}]->[{}]/[{}], all_pools {}
```

The braces are substituted using the values below, in using their positional order. So the first {}, reading left to right, is replaced by the value of "name" and the last one with the value returned by pools.apply(lastJvmStats, currentJvmStats).

```
 name,
 seq,
 totalGcCollectionCount,
 currentGcCollectionTime,
 currentGcCollectionCount,
 TimeValue.timeValueMillis(elapsed),
 currentGcCollectionTime,
 totalGcCollectionTime,
 lastJvmStats.getMem().getHeapUsed(),
 currentJvmStats.getMem().getHeapUsed(),
 maxHeapUsed,
 pools.apply(lastJvmStats, currentJvmStats)
```